# Oracle SSO URL regex to exclude if URL has an specific param

Tags: java, regex, jsp, single-sign-on

Currently, we have SSO enabled in our web application and works well. But, when an user is configured in SSO but not in our web application, we are having a redirect loop.

We have noticed that, when this happens, webapp invokes an URL like this:

```
/login.jsp?errormsg=The+User%3A+SOMEUSER+doesn%27t+exist
```

And my configuration of enforced URLs is the next:

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri[0] = /
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri[1] = /-*-.jsp
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri[2] = /-*-.jsp*
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri[3] = /-*-.jsp?*
...
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri.invert = true
```

I enforce all jsps to be validated through SSO. But, what i want to do is to define an URI like:

- If an .jsp is being invoked, but it doesn't have **errormsg** parameter in it, validate session through SSO;
- But if an .jsp is being invoked and **errormsg** parameter is in the URL, don't validate it, let it go.

The thing is, can i use regular expressions on SSO URIs? Because those patterns

**/-*-.jsp**

as far as i know, aren't regular expressions.

How can i create that filter?

Comment: Would you consider changing the requirement slightly such that *only* a .jsp with the `errormsg` parameter in it is not validated and everything else (including not .jsp) is validated?

Answer (score 1):

You're right in thinking the [not enforced list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-4803/gataa/index.html) pattern in AMAgent.properties isn't a regular expression. As it seems you've already discovered, it uses a far more limited [wildcard matching syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-4803/ghhpa/index.html).

The answer to the question *"Can I use regular expressions on SSO URIs?"* seems to be no. Unfortunately what can be done here is very limited as the syntax does not include a way of excluding particular characters or phrases. Without further understanding the requirements, my best suggestion would be to use an exclude list rather than an include list:

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri[0] = /-*-.jsp?errormsg*
...
```

(with `com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.uri.invert = false`)

Of course you may need to add many further entries to this list and it may become large but at least it is more compliant with Oracle's advice:

> When the not-enforced list is inverted, the number of resources for
>   which the agent will not enforce access control is potentially very
>   large. The use of this feature should therefore be used with extreme
>   caution and only after extensive evaluation of the security
>   requirements of the deployed applications.